# Jboss fail connection

Tags: java, eclipse, jboss, java-web-start

I am pretty new in jboss and web service world :)
I am trying to build a web service that should be give json response to a mobile app.
First i have created a Dynamic web project in Eclipse, with hibernate and EJB for persistence and logic. i am using my jboss 7.1 final as server to run my war. The problem is that, it seems to work the EJB part but then the log says the 'remote connection failed'. I am trying to run jboss from eclipse doing the 'run on server'.
What should i check to solve this issue? Maybe some config in the project or in the standalone.xml?
Thank in advance, here is the log

```
10:37:32,179 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] JBoss Modules version 1.1.1.GA
10:37:32,392 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] JBoss MSC version 1.0.2.GA
10:37:32,440 INFO  [org.jboss.as] JBAS015899: JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final "Brontes" starting
10:37:33,267 INFO  [org.xnio] XNIO Version 3.0.3.GA
10:37:33,267 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] JBAS015888: Creating http management service using socket-binding (management-http)
10:37:33,278 INFO  [org.xnio.nio] XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.0.3.GA
10:37:33,286 INFO  [org.jboss.remoting] JBoss Remoting version 3.2.3.GA
10:37:33,313 INFO  [org.jboss.as.logging] JBAS011502: Removing bootstrap log handlers
10:37:33,409 INFO  [org.jboss.as.webservices] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 48) JBAS015537: Activating WebServices Extension
10:37:33,401 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 44) JBAS013101: Activating Security Subsystem
10:37:33,397 INFO  [org.jboss.as.osgi] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 39) JBAS011940: Activating OSGi Subsystem
10:37:33,396 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 38) JBAS011800: Activating Naming Subsystem
10:37:33,369 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS010408: Starting JCA Subsystem (JBoss IronJacamar 1.0.9.Final)
10:37:33,318 INFO  [org.jboss.as.configadmin] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 26) JBAS016200: Activating ConfigAdmin Subsystem
10:37:33,433 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS013100: Current PicketBox version=4.0.7.Final
10:37:33,462 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS011802: Starting Naming Service
10:37:33,467 INFO  [org.jboss.as.mail.extension] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS015400: Bound mail session [java:jboss/mail/Default]
10:37:33,335 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 31) JBAS010280: Activating Infinispan subsystem.
10:37:33,473 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 27) JBAS010404: Deploying non-JDBC-compliant driver class com.mysql.jdbc.Driver (version 5.1)
10:37:33,639 INFO  [org.jboss.ws.common.management.AbstractServerConfig] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBoss Web Services - Stack CXF Server 4.0.2.GA
10:37:33,884 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS015012: Started FileSystemDeploymentService for directory C:\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\standalone\deployments
10:37:33,886 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS015014: Re-attempting failed deployment FaultManager_WebService.war
10:37:33,899 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS015003: Found FaultManager_WebService.war in deployment directory. To trigger deployment create a file called FaultManager_WebService.war.dodeploy
10:37:34,109 INFO  [org.jboss.as.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS017100: Listening on localhost/127.0.0.1:4447
10:37:34,123 INFO  [org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol] (MSC service thread 1-6) Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080
10:37:34,204 INFO  [org.jboss.as.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS017100: Listening on localhost/127.0.0.1:9999
10:37:34,307 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS010400: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/faultmgrds]
10:37:34,369 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "FaultManager_WebService.war"
10:37:34,772 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS011401: Read persistence.xml for fmservice
10:37:34,942 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.EjbJndiBindingsDeploymentUnitProcessor] (MSC service thread 1-4) JNDI bindings for session bean named DisserviziWS in deployment unit deployment "FaultManager_WebService.war" are as follows:

    java:global/FaultManager_WebService/DisserviziWS!com.alten.ws.DisserviziWS
    java:app/FaultManager_WebService/DisserviziWS!com.alten.ws.DisserviziWS
    java:module/DisserviziWS!com.alten.ws.DisserviziWS
    java:global/FaultManager_WebService/DisserviziWS
    java:app/FaultManager_WebService/DisserviziWS
    java:module/DisserviziWS

10:37:34,945 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.EjbJndiBindingsDeploymentUnitProcessor] (MSC service thread 1-4) JNDI bindings for session bean named DisserviziDaoImpl in deployment unit deployment "FaultManager_WebService.war" are as follows:

    java:global/FaultManager_WebService/DisserviziDaoImpl!com.alten.dao.DisserviziDAO
    java:app/FaultManager_WebService/DisserviziDaoImpl!com.alten.dao.DisserviziDAO
    java:module/DisserviziDaoImpl!com.alten.dao.DisserviziDAO
    java:global/FaultManager_WebService/DisserviziDaoImpl
    java:app/FaultManager_WebService/DisserviziDaoImpl
    java:module/DisserviziDaoImpl

10:37:35,286 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS015951: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990
10:37:35,287 ERROR [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS015875: JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final "Brontes" started (with errors) in 3351ms - Started 186 of 276 services (13 services failed or missing dependencies, 76 services are passive or on-demand)
10:37:35,481 ERROR [org.jboss.remoting.remote.connection] (Remoting "20160170-ait:MANAGEMENT" read-1) JBREM000200: Remote connection failed: java.io.IOException: Connessione interrotta dal software del computer host
10:37:35,492 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS015870: Deploy of deployment "FaultManager_WebService.war" was rolled back with failure message {"JBAS014771: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => ["jboss.persistenceunit.\"FaultManager_WebService.war#fmservice\"jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.datasources.WorkCenterDSMissing[jboss.persistenceunit.\"FaultManager_WebService.war#fmservice\"jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.datasources.WorkCenterDS]"]}
10:37:35,508 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment FaultManager_WebService.war in 17ms
10:37:35,510 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014775:    New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:
      service jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.datasources.WorkCenterDS (missing) dependents: [service jboss.persistenceunit."FaultManager_WebService.war#fmservice"] 

10:37:35,513 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) {"JBAS014653: Composite operation failed and was rolled back. Steps that failed:" => {"Operation step-2" => {"JBAS014771: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => ["jboss.persistenceunit.\"FaultManager_WebService.war#fmservice\"jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.datasources.WorkCenterDSMissing[jboss.persistenceunit.\"FaultManager_WebService.war#fmservice\"jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.datasources.WorkCenterDS]"]}}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your application FaultManager_WebService has unsatisfied dependencies:

```
JBAS014775:    New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:
      service jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.datasources.WorkCenterDS (missing) dependents: [service jboss.persistenceunit."FaultManager_WebService.war#fmservice"]
```

Check if this link could solve your problem:

https://developer.jboss.org/thread/205409